# fs.watch vs setInterval in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have application where i am reading data from csv file at every interval of 500ms.

CSV file is changed at every 300ms from another desktop based application.

So which one is better to use fs.watch or setInterval in this case.

Comment: Why would you want to watch for the change if you know the interval? Seems like a no brainer to me. FWIW reading a file twice per/sec would be pretty resource intensive, I'd consider changing the interval if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I'l go with `fs.watch` it is helping me to create a more robust architecture.

Let's assume we are using timers `setTimeout|setInterval`, we need to hardcode the delay, and meanwhile the front application is scaling up and is updating the csv faster or slower, then you will need to modify your code so using `fs.watch` you just don't care how many change events occured, your application will not need any changes.

The biggest issue that I see at the moment with `fs.watch` is if the front will update the csv so fast that you will not finish your import and a new event will be dispatched then you will have hard time to deal with race conditions, but till that moment `fs.watch` is a good call imo.